# Receive NSNotification method not calling

Tags: ios, iphone

I have use below for for register notification:-

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(AllSearch:) name:filter object:nil];


-(void)AllSearch:(NSNotification *)notification
{
NSLog(@"abc");    
}
```

and i post notification with this code:-

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:filter object:nil];
```

But "**AllSearch**" Method not calling.

Comment: Is the object observing still in memory when you post the notification? Is the addObserver done before posting ?

Comment: I have Use this first
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:filter object:nil];
}

And, i have use in other ViewController.
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(AllSearch:) name:filter object:nil];

Now i am on viewController Class. and when we scroll the tableview 
"AllSearch" not calling.

Comment: @HariMohan you have to first this code [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(AllSearch:) name:filter object:nil];

Comment: after  addObserver  postnotification [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:filter object:nil];

Answer (score 0):

plz check you code you have to addObserver first

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(AllSearch:) name:filter object:nil];
```

befor postNotification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:filter object:nil];
```